# Calling multiple functions with code within fails to call both, only calls the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to call multiple functions fails.

it only calls the first one, not the second, I mean it has to call both of them.

I use native Javascript then JQuery but still failling.
When I take out the code and just leave the alert("") message, it successfully calls multiple functions. The problem is my functions have to contain codes, not only simple alert statement.

I tried various example from Search but still giving me the same issue which is when I take out the code and leave only the alert message, it works perfect.!!!

```html
 
    <b>Number of items</b> (between 2 and 50):
    <input type="number" name="numbItem" min="2" max="50" id="numbItem"> &nbsp&nbsp
    <button id='createItem' type="button">Create</button>
               
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
         document.getElementById("createItem").onclick = function() 
         {
                var numItems= document.getElementById("numbItem").value;
          //alert (price);
          //alert (numItems + " items created.")
          
          if (numItems < 2) 
          {
              alert("Can't create just 1 Item;" + "\n" + "Please make sure to enter a number betwen 2 and 50.");
                    document.body.innerHTML = "";    // Clear Screen
                    document.location.reload();      // Refresh Page
          }
          else if (numItems > 50) 
          {
                    alert("Can't create more than 50 Items;" + "\n" + "Please make sure to enter a number betwen 2 and 50.");
                    document.body.innerHTML = "";   // Clear Screen
                    document.location.reload();      // Refresh Page
                }
                else 
                {
                    
                    alert(numItems + " Items being created. . .");
                    
                }
              
            };
        
        </script>

        <div id=userForms></div>
        <br>
        
       
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="sumValue" id="sumValueId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Sum" id="btnSumValueId">
        &nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="sumTaxe" id="sumTaxeId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13"> <input type="submit" value="Sum" id="btnSumTaxeId">
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="submit" value="Get Totals" id="btnGetTotals" style="width: 140px; position: absolute; left: 550x;">
        
        <br><br>Total Monthly Expenditure&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="totalExpend" id="totalExpValueId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Total" id="btnTotalExpValueId">
        
        <br><br>Effective Tax Rate as %&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="EffectivTaxRate" id="EffectivTaxRateId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Total" id="btnEffectivTaxRateId">
        
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        console.log( "ready!" );

        $( "#createItem" ).click(function() {
            var totalRows = $('#numbItem').val();
            
            var formHtml = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
            {
                formHtml += '&nbsp;<input type="text" name="item'+i+'"  placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value'+i+'" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" id="ValueId'+i+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc" id="TaxeId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="vat'+i+'" min="0" max="100" id="VatId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="btnItem'+i+'" value="Calculate" type="button" id="btnCalcId'+i+'"><br><br>';

            }
            
            
            $('#userForms').html(formHtml);
    
 
        });

    });


    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { student(); });
    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { calculate(); });
    
 
        function calculate(){
        //alert("Good Morning"); 
                    
                    //alert('FRONT !!!');
                    
                    var total = 10;
                    for( var i = 3; i <= 50; i++ ) 
                    {
                        var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
                        
                        //alert(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
                        document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value;
                        
                        if(val>0)
                        {
                           total += val;
                        }
                        
                        document.getElementById("sumValueId").value = total;
                        
                    }
                    
                    
                    
    }
    
    function student(){
        //alert("Hi my name is Sunny");
         
                    //alert('FRONT !!!');
                    
                    var total1 = 55;
                    for( var i1 = 2; i1 <= 50; i1++ ) 
                    {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("TaxeId" + i1).value);
                        
                        //alert(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
                        document.getElementById("TaxeId" + i1).value;
                        
                        if(val1>0)
                        {
                           total1 += val1;
                        }
                        
                        document.getElementById("sumTaxeId").value = total1;
                        
                    }
 
                
    }
        
    </script>
   

</body>
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: it's only calling the first function, not both.

Comment: @Chloe: When you debug, where/how *specifically* does it fail?  Is there an error on the browser's debugging console?  What happens if you put both function calls in *one* click handler instead of *two* click handlers?  What if you swap the order of the two function calls in that *one* click handler?

Comment: Please provide the HTML that is necessary to run this script. Maybe your sum elements are not `input` elements? Or maybe you don't have all the `input` elements up to an `id` with 50 in it? We cannot tell without you giving us the info.

Comment: there's no error. the only thing that's occurring is it's only call the first function, not both. I tried to put both function calls in one click handler instead of two click handlers. I also tried to swap the order but still not calling both, only the first that is called.

Comment: HTML is fine and work perfect. Everything is working perfect if put in separate button, cause I even started with each input with its own button and is working FINE...  but I realized that I'm having many buttons, that's why I decide to have only one button to call everything through functions.

Comment: I can only repeat that without the HTML we cannot do much for you. I vote to close this question as the info given is not enough to reproduce the problem. See a working version here (with only id values up to 5): https://jsfiddle.net/z979vu10/

Comment: IT IS in separate button at this moment and it works fine. I'm just testing the code to have one button calling all these functions and that code which is the above code fails.

Comment: It doesn't fail here: https://jsfiddle.net/z979vu10/, so you're doing something wrong that is not documented in your question. Provide the HTML. NB: For this question it does not seem relevant you have about 50 inputs for each category. Please minimise the problem to the essence.

Comment: I see in the link you provided that it really doesn't fail. so I edited the above code and added the whole code.

Comment: By the way, I'm running that code in CPanel, not in local. Just to let you know !!

Comment: Please can someone help?

Comment: @Chloe: The code that's been added to the question is too much, there is tons of unrelated noise in there.  Please provide a *minimal* example which is complete enough to demonstrate the problem.  Insisting that "everything works perfect" is not helpful debugging information.

Comment: I re-edited the above code again, and only left the minimal one. The issue is **it's only calling the first function**. I tried to reverse it as shown in the above code but still not working.

Comment: @ trincot. I posted the HTML you wanted.

Comment: @Chloe Please check my new answer if that helps you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as a new answer because you modified the code after my previous answer:

Several Pointers:

- To give spaces use `&nbsp;` in place of `&nbsp`
- In place of using two bind functions you can call a single one like so:

See below:

```
$('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() {
    student();
    calculate();
});
```

You are getting an error in the following code in both of your functions:

```
for( var i = 3; i <= 50; i++ ) 
{
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
}
```

What this does is it iterates from 3 or 2 upto 50 which is wrong as there are not 50 elements if the user selects only 2.

Thus giving you an error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

So you should enclose your appended code in a common div and then run the loop upto its length like so:

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
    {
        formHtml += '<div class="newFORM">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="item'+i+'"  placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value'+i+'" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" id="ValueId'+i+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc" id="TaxeId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="vat'+i+'" min="0" max="100" id="VatId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="btnItem'+i+'" value="Calculate" type="button" id="btnCalcId'+i+'"><br><br></div>';

    }
```

Notice the class `newFORM` ...

Now whenever I run the loop it should be less than the length of all the classes:

```
for( var i = 1; i <= $('.newFORM').length; i++ ) 
{
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);

    //alert(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
    document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value;

    if(val>0)
    {
       total += val;
    }

    document.getElementById("sumValueId").value = total;

}
```

Hope that helps:

See the demo now:

```html
    
    <p><h3>Budget Calculator TEST [ver 1.0]</h3>**********************************</p>
    <b>Number of items</b> (between 2 and 50):
    <input type="number" name="numbItem" min="2" max="50" id="numbItem"> &nbsp&nbsp
    <button id='createItem' type="button">Create</button>
    
                 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
         document.getElementById("createItem").onclick = function() 
         {
                var numItems= document.getElementById("numbItem").value;
          //alert (price);
          //alert (numItems + " items created.")
          
          if (numItems < 2) 
          {
              alert("Can't create just 1 Item;" + "\n" + "Please make sure to enter a number betwen 2 and 50.");
                    document.body.innerHTML = "";    // Clear Screen
                    document.location.reload();      // Refresh Page
          }
          else if (numItems > 50) 
          {
              
                    alert("Can't create more than 50 Items;" + "\n" + "Please make sure to enter a number betwen 2 and 50.");
                    document.body.innerHTML = "";   // Clear Screen
                    document.location.reload();      // Refresh Page
                }
                else 
                {
                    
                    alert(numItems + " Items being created. . .");
                    
                }
              
            };
        
        </script>

        <div id=userForms></div>
        <br>
        
       
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="sumValue" id="sumValueId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Sum" id="btnSumValueId">
        &nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="sumTaxe" id="sumTaxeId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13"> <input type="submit" value="Sum" id="btnSumTaxeId">
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="submit" value="Get Totals" id="btnGetTotals" style="width: 140px; position: absolute; left: 550x;">
        
        <br><br>Total Monthly Expenditure&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="totalExpend" id="totalExpValueId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Total" id="btnTotalExpValueId">
        
        <br><br>Effective Tax Rate as %&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="EffectivTaxRate" id="EffectivTaxRateId" readonly style="background:#bdf584" size="13">
        <input type="submit" value="Total" id="btnEffectivTaxRateId">
        
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        console.log( "ready!" );

        $( "#createItem" ).click(function() {
            var totalRows = $('#numbItem').val();
            
            var formHtml = '';
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
            {
                formHtml += '<div class="newFORM">&nbsp;<input type="text" name="item'+i+'"  placeholder="E.g.: Gross Salary" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="value'+i+'" placeholder="E.g.: 12000" id="ValueId'+i+'"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tax'+i+'" value="" readonly style="color:#f00;background:#ccc" id="TaxeId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="number" name="vat'+i+'" min="0" max="100" id="VatId'+i+'">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="btnItem'+i+'" value="Calculate" type="button" id="btnCalcId'+i+'"><br><br></div>';

            }
            
            
            $('#userForms').html(formHtml);
    
 
        });

    });


    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { student(); });
    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { calculate(); });
    
 
        function calculate(){
        alert("Good Morning"); 
                    
                    //alert('FRONT !!!');
                    
                    var total = 10;
for( var i = 1; i <= $('.newFORM').length; i++ ) 
{
    var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
    
    //alert(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
    document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value;
    
    if(val>0)
    {
       total += val;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("sumValueId").value = total;
    
}
                    
                    
                    
    }
    
    function student(){
        alert("Hi my name is Sunny");
         
                    //alert('FRONT !!!');
                    
                    var total1 = 55;
                    for( var i1 = 1; i1 <= $('.newFORM').length; i1++ ) 
                    {
                        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("TaxeId" + i1).value);
                        
                        //alert(document.getElementById("ValueId" + i).value);
                        document.getElementById("TaxeId" + i1).value;
                        
                        if(val1>0)
                        {
                           total1 += val1;
                        }
                        
                        document.getElementById("sumTaxeId").value = total1;
                        
                    }
 
                
    }
        
    </script>
```

Comment: Cool. let me check this out. will let you know. Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Chloe sure go ahead. Let me know if you face issues further.

Comment: Thank you so so much user **Shakti Phartiyal**. It's solved !!!  I have couple of questions. How did you get the error "**Cannot read property 'value' of null**" cause I'm using Notepad++ that flipping gives me no error message !!!  Have to figure it out by myself. Are you using another software?? Can you please suggest me which one to use?

Comment: @Chole the error is clearly visible in the browser's error console. If using chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+I or F12 to open the debugger tools.. in the console section you can see all errors and warnings..

Comment: Thanks so much. By the way, what software do you use ? apart from Notepad+

Comment: @Chole I never use notepad++ I use PHP Storm or in rare cases Sublime text

Comment: Thanks. Tell me one more thing. Does PHP Storm display error message like Google Chrome (Developer Tools) which you showed me in the previous post? Cause I need something which will help me debug the program fast as using Notepad++ doesn't help me.

Comment: @Chole No those errors are shown only when the code runs on a browser as they are runtime errors. But yes basic syntax errors are displayed

Comment: Okay. So why do I need PHP Storm over Notepad++ ?? if you can tell me your own experience on it? please pros and cons !

Comment: @Chloe you do not "NEED" PHP Storm, its just a matter of preference and ease of use.  Read more at https://stackshare.io/stackups/notepad-plus-plus-vs-phpstorm#more

Comment: Thanks so much for everything. I appreciate that !

Answer (score 5):

The error is because you cannot use **class** as a function name.

Convert it to classX or anything else it will work.

Example:

```js
    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { classX(); });
    $('#btnGetTotals').bind('click', function() { student(); });
    
    function classX(){
        alert("Good Morning"); 
    }

    function student(){
        alert("Hi my name is Test");                
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <button id="btnGetTotals">
       GO
       </button>
```

**Update**

It is basic to know that you cannot use reserved keywords to name your functions or variables:

See the list of reserved keywords at:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: I just use "class" as example in the post. Its real name is "calculate"

Comment: @Chloe, please make sure the code in your question reproduces the behaviour you describe, otherwise you waste the time of people looking into it. If you wanted to change "calculate" by "class" (why?), then you should test that before posting.